# Flink - processing consecutive events within time constraint

Tags: apache-flink, window-functions, flink-streaming

I have a use case and I think I need some help on how to approach it.
Because I am new to streaming and Flink I will try to be very descriptive in what I am trying to achieve. Sorry if I am not using to formal and correct language.

My code will be in java but I do not care to get code in python or just pseudo code or approach.

**TL:DR**

1. Group events of same key that are within some time limit.
2. Out of those events, create a result event only from the 2 most closest (time domain) events.
3. This require (I think) opening a window for each and every event that comes.
4. If you'll look ahead at the batch solution you will understand best my problem.

**Background:**

1. I have data coming from sensors as a stream from Kafka.
2. I need to use eventTime because that data comes unrecorded. The lateness that will give me 90% of events is about 1 minute.
3. I am grouping those events by some key.

**What I want to do:**

1. Depending on some event's fields - I would like to "join/mix" 2 events into a new event ("result event").
2. The first condition is that those consecutive events are WITHIN 30 seconds from each other.
3. The next conditions are simply checking some fields values and than deciding.

**My psuedo solution:**

1. open a new window for EACH event. That window should be of 1 minute.
2. For every event that comes within that minute - I want to check it's event time and see if it is 30 seconds from the initial window event. If yes - check for other condition and omit a new result stream.

**The Problem - When a new event comes it needs to:**

1. create a new window for itself.
2. Join only ONE window out of SEVERAL possible windows that are 30 seconds from it.

**The question:**

Is that possible?

In other words my connection is between two "consecutive" events only.

Thank you very much.

**Maybe showing the solution for **BATCH** case will show what I am trying to do best:**

```
for i in range(grouped_events.length):
    event_A = grouped_events[i]
    event_B = grouped_events[i+1]
    if event_B.get("time") - event_A.get("time") < 30:
        if event_B.get("color") == event_A.get("color"):
            if event_B.get("size") > event_A.get("size"):
                create_result_event(event_A, event_B)
```

**My (naive) tries so far with Flink in java**

**The sum function is just a place holder for my function to create a new result object...

1. First solution is just doing a simple time window and summing by some field
2. Second is trying to do some process function on the window and maybe there iterate throw all events and check for my conditions?

   ```
   DataStream
   .keyBy(threeEvent -> threeEvent.getUserId())
   .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
   .sum("size")
   .print();



   DataStream
   .keyBy(threeEvent -> threeEvent.getUserId())
   .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
   .process(new processFunction());



   public static class processFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<ThreeEvent, Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>, Long, TimeWindow> {
       @Override
       public void process(Long key, Context context, Iterable<ThreeEvent> threeEvents, Collector<Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>> out) throws Exception {
           Float sumOfSize = 0F;
           for (ThreeEvent f : threeEvents) {
               sumOfSize += f.getSize();
           }

           out.collect(new Tuple3<>(context.window().getEnd(), key, sumOfTips));
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can, of course, use windows to create mini-batches that you sort and analyze, but it will be difficult to handle the window boundaries correctly (what if the events that should be paired land in different windows?).

This looks like it would be much more easily done with a keyed stream and a stateful flatmap. Just use a RichFlatMapFunction and use one piece of keyed state (a ValueState) that remembers the previous event for each key. Then as each event is processed, compare it to the saved event, produce a result if that should happen, and update the state.

You can read about working with flink's keyed state in the [flink training](https://training.ververica.com/lessons/stateful.html) and in the [flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/state/).

The one thing that concerns me about your use case is whether or not your events may arrive out-of-order. Is it the case that to get correct results you would need to first sort the events by timestamp? That isn't trivial. If this is a concern, then I would suggest that you use [Flink SQL with MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html), or the [CEP library](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/libs/cep.html), both of which are designed for doing pattern recognition on event streams, and will take care of sorting the stream for you (you just have to provide timestamps and watermarks).

This query may not be exactly right, but hopefully conveys the flavor of how to do something like this with match recognize:

```
SELECT * FROM Events
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY userId
  ORDER BY eventTime
  MEASURES
    A.userId as userId,
    A.color as color,
    A.size as aSize,
    B.size as bSize
  AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
  PATTERN (A B)
  DEFINE
    A AS true,
    B AS ( timestampDiff(SECOND, A.eventTime, B.eventTime) < 30) 
           AND A.color = B.color 
           AND A.size < B.size )
);
```

This can also be done quite naturally with CEP, where the basis for comparing consecutive events is to use an [iterative condition](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/libs/cep.html#conditions), and you can use a `within` clause to handle the time constraint.

Comment: keyed stream is just keyby some key, that is not the problem. so you are saying using a richflatmap? how in that every event (after grouped by some key) is openning it's own window? only flink sql has pattern, not stream api also?

Comment: Why use the window API for this use case? I don't see any windows in your batch example. It looks like the logic only requires comparing sequential pairs of events. Flink SQL runs on streams and batches, but only supports patterns on streams.

Comment: can you show the most simple example of usage (python / java) that will show the approach you are talking about?

Comment: what is the difference between your CEP approach and using a simple tumbling/sliding window of 1 minute and processing the events each minute? in that processing function ill first sort the events and than ill just do my for loop like in the batch case. i am emitting watermarks and time stamps. as I wrote 1 minute is will give 90% of accurate watermark.

Comment: I read about CEP - my conditions are not based on each and one events (e.g. size>10) but on the relation between those events value.. (e.g. eventb_size-eventa_size == 4) how can I deal with that?

Comment: the sql syntex does not feel right. both api give the same results under the hood? started reading the CEP but seems complicated (although it does look like what i am looking for). can you show an example of the within? I read about the ".next" that you can specify "within" but I need the "closest" event. meaning if i have 10:00:00 and 10:00:10 and 10:00:15, even both are under 30 seconds, only the second one will be used to create my result object. also I need to deal with discarding events that are sent to several patterns and use only one.

Comment: I think you are probably right that `within` isn't helpful in your case.

Comment: So? Any ideas? :)

Comment: Just do the same as elsewhere; compare the timestamps on consecutive events.

Comment: How can I access values of first event when I'm in the condition of the second event?

Comment: ctx.getEventsForPattern(...)

Comment: "This looks like it would be much more easily done with a keyed stream and a stateful flatmap. Just use a RichFlatMapFunction and use one piece of keyed state (a ValueState) that remembers the previous event for each key. Then as each event is processed, compare it to the saved event, produce a result if that should happen, and update the state." - this will not work if my events are coming out of order?

Comment: With that simple approach, consecutive events will be ordered non-deterministically rather than by timestamp, unless you can somehow guarantee their ordering.